# unable to get the score and game over/reset functions to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am having problems with the below code. Can someone please help and explain why the game over/reset and score functions are not working?
Below is the code im working from. My problem is that i can not see why the game over/reset function does not work. When the ship crashes into an astroid the game abruptly ends, but when it crashes into the barrier it does not indicate game over. Also, it's not reflecting the score.
Sorry if i wasn't clear before.

## Here starts the code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')
 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Canvas
from kivy.config import Config
from functools import partial
from random import *
 
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 1.)
 
 
class MyButton(Button):
#class used to get uniform button styles
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = Window.width*0.018
 
 
class SmartMenu(Widget):
#the instance created by this class will appear
#when the game is started for the first time
    buttonList = []
 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #create custom events first
        self.register_event_type('on_button_release')
        super(SmartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.layout.width = Window.width/2
        self.layout.height = Window.height/2
        self.layout.x = Window.width/2 - self.layout.width/2
        self.layout.y = Window.height/2 - self.layout.height/2
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
 
    def on_button_release(self, *args):
        #print 'The on_button_release event was just dispatched', args
        #don't need to do anything here. needed for dispatch
        pass
 
    def callback(self,instance):
    #print('The button %s is being pressed' % instance.text)
        self.buttonText = instance.text
        self.dispatch('on_button_release') #dispatching the callback event 'on_button_release' to tell teh parent instance to read the button text
 
    def addButtons(self):
        for k in self.buttonList:
            tmpBtn = MyButton(text = k)
            tmpBtn.background_color = [.4, .4, .4, .4]
            tmpBtn.bind(on_release = self.callback) #when the button is released the callback function is called
            self.layout.add_widget(tmpBtn)
 
    def buildUp(self):
    #self.colorWindow()
        self.addButtons()
 
 
class SmartStartMenu(SmartMenu):
#setup the menu button names
    buttonList = ['start', 'about']
 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SmartStartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.layout.width = Window.width/2
        self.layout.height = Window.height/2
        self.layout.x = Window.width/2 - self.layout.width/2
        self.layout.y = Window.height/2 - self.layout.height/2
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
 
        self.msg = Label(text = 'Flappy Ship')
        self.msg.font_size = Window.width*0.07
        self.msg.pos = (Window.width*0.45,Window.height*0.75)
        self.add_widget(self.msg)
        self.img = Image(source = 'lens2.png')
        self.img.size = (Window.width*1.5,Window.height*1.5)
        self.img.pos = (-Window.width*0.2,-Window.height*0.2)
        self.img.opacity = 0.35
        self.add_widget(self.img)
 
 
class WidgetDrawer(Widget):
#This widget is used to draw all of the objects on the screen
#it handles the following:
# widget movement, size, positioning
    def __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetDrawer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.size = (Window.width*.002*25,Window.width*.002*25)
            self.rect_bg=Rectangle(source=imageStr, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_graphics_pos)
            self.x = self.center_x
            self.y = self.center_y
            self.pos = (self.x, self.y)
            self.rect_bg.pos = self.pos
 
    def update_graphics_pos(self, instance, value):
        self.rect_bg.pos = value
 
    def setSize(self, width, height):
        self.size = (width, height)
 
    def setPos(self, xpos, ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos
 
 
class ScoreWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScoreWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.asteroidScore = 0
        self.currentScore = 0
        with self.canvas:
            tmpPos = (Window.width*0.25, Window.height*0.25)
            tmpSize = (Window.width*0.5, Window.height*0.5)
            Color(0.1, .1, .1)
            self.scoreRect = Rectangle(pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)
 
    def prepare(self):
        #calculate the score
        try:
            self.finalScore = self.asteroidScore*100
        except:
            print 'problems getting score'
            self.animateScore()
 
    def animateScore(self):
        #display score at 0 and every time interval add 100 until
        #we reach the final score
        #draw a score widget and schedule updates
        scoreText = 'Score: 0'# + str(self.finalScore)
        self.scoreLabel = Label(text=scoreText,font_size = '20sp')
        self.scoreLabel.x = Window.width*0.3
        self.scoreLabel.y = Window.height*0.3
        self.add_widget(self.scoreLabel)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.updateScore, .1)
        self.drawStars()
 
    def updateScore(self,dt):
        self.currentScore = self.currentScore +100
        self.scoreLabel.text = 'Score: ' + str(self.currentScore)
        if self.currentScore < self.finalScore:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.updateScore, 0.1)
 
    def drawStars(self):
        #0-10 asteroids 0 stars
        #11-50 asteroids 1 star
        #51-200 asteroids 2 stars
        #201-500 asteroids 3 stars
        #501-1000 asteroids 4 stars
        #1001+ asteroids 5 stars
        starNumber = 0
        if self.asteroidScore > 10:
            starNumber = 1
        if self.asteroidScore > 50:
            starNumber = 2
        if self.asteroidScore > 200:
            starNumber = 3
        if self.asteroidScore > 500:
            starNumber = 4
        if self.asteroidScore > 1000:
            starNumber = 5
 
        with self.canvas:
        #draw stars
        #rect one
            starPos = Window.width*0.27, Window.height*0.42
            starSize = Window.width*0.06,Window.width*0.06
            starString = 'gold_star.png'
            if starNumber < 1:
                starString = 'gray_star.png'
            starRectOne = Rectangle(source=starString,pos=starPos, size = starSize)
            #rect two
            starPos = Window.width*0.37, Window.height*0.42
            if starNumber < 2:
                starString = 'gray_star.png'
            starRectTwo = Rectangle(source=starString,pos=starPos, size = starSize)
            #rect three
            starPos = Window.width*0.47, Window.height*0.42
            if starNumber < 3:
                starString = 'gray_star.png'
            starRectThree = Rectangle(source=starString,pos=starPos, size = starSize)
            #rect four
            starPos = Window.width*0.57, Window.height*0.42
            if starNumber < 4:
                starString = 'gray_star.png'
            starRectFour = Rectangle(source=starString,pos=starPos, size = starSize)
            #rect five
            starPos = Window.width*0.67, Window.height*0.42
            if starNumber < 5:
                starString = 'gray_star.png'
                starRectFive = Rectangle(source=starString,pos=starPos, size = starSize)
 
 
class Asteroid(WidgetDrawer):
    #Asteroid class. The flappy ship will dodge these
    imageStr = './sandstone_1.png'
    rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr)
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
 
    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x*5
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y
 
    def update(self):
        self.move()
 
 
class Ship(WidgetDrawer):
#Ship class. This is for the main ship object.
#velocity of ship on x/y axis
#setup constants, health, etc
#choose default image:
 
    impulse = 3
    grav = -0.1
 
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    flameSize = (Window.width*.03, Window.width*.03)
 
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.velocity_x
        self.y += self.velocity_y
 
    #don't let the ship go too far
        if self.y < Window.height*0.05:
        #give upwards impulse
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            self.explode()
        if self.y > Window.height*0.95:
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            self.explode()
 
    def checkBulletNPCCollision(self, j):
        if self.k.collide_widget(j):
            j.health = j.health - self.k.bulletDamage
            j.attackFlag = 'True'
        #age the bullet
            self.k.age = self.k.lifespan+10
 
    def checkBulletStageCollision(self,q):
        if self.k.collide_widget(q):
        #if object type is asteorid
            try:
                if q.type == 'asteroid':
                    q.health = q.health - self.k.bulletDamage
                    self.k.age = self.k.lifespan+10
            except:
                print 'couldnt hit asteroid'
 
    def determineVelocity(self):
        #move the ship up and down
        #we need to take into account our acceleration
        #also want to look at gravity
        self.grav = self.grav*1.05 #increase gravity
        #set a grav limit
        if self.grav < -4:
             self.grav = -4
        self.velocity_y = self.impulse + self.grav
        self.impulse = 0.95*self.impulse
 
    def drawArrow(self, *largs):
        #draw the arrows directly onto the canvas
        with self.canvas:
             flamePos = (self.pos[0]-Window.width*.02, self.pos[1]+Window.width*.01)
             flameRect = Rectangle(source='./flame.png', pos=flamePos, size=self.flameSize)
             #schedule removal
 
        def removeArrows(arrow, *largs):
             self.canvas.remove(arrow)
 
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeArrows, flameRect), .5)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateArrows, flameRect), 0.1)
 
    def updateArrows(self, arrow, dt):
        with self.canvas:
            arrow.pos = (arrow.pos[0]-10, arrow.pos[1])
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateArrows, arrow), 0.1)
        return
 
    def explode(self):
        tmpSize = Window.width*0.25,Window.width*0.2
        tmpPos = (self.x-Window.width*0.095, self.y-Window.width*0.08)
 
        with self.canvas:
            self.explosionRect = Rectangle(source ='./explosion1.png',pos=tmpPos,size=tmpSize)
 
        def changeExplosion(rect, newSource, *largs):
            rect.source = newSource
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion2.png'), 0.2)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion3.png'), 0.4)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion4.png'), 0.6)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion5.png'), 0.8)
 
        def removeExplosion(rect, *largs):
            self.canvas.remove(rect)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeExplosion, self.explosionRect), 1)
 
    def update(self):
        self.determineVelocity()
        self.move()
 
 
class GUI(Widget):
#this is the main widget that contains the game. This is the primary object
#that runs
    asteroidList =[]
#important to use numericproperty here so we can bind a callback
#to use every time the number changes
    asteroidScore = NumericProperty(0)
    minProb = 1780
 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
        #setup label for the score
        self.score = Label(text = '0')
        self.score.y = Window.height*0.8
        self.score.x = Window.width*0.2
 
        def check_score(self, obj):
            #update credits
            self.score.text = str(self.asteroidScore)
            self.bind(asteroidScore = check_score)
            self.add_widget(self.score)
 
        #now we create a ship object
        self.ship = Ship(imageStr = './ship.png')
        self.ship.x = Window.width/4
        self.ship.y = Window.height/2
        self.add_widget(self.ship)
#self.ship.drawArrow()#start the flames
        Clock.schedule_interval((self.ship.drawArrow), 0.1)
 
    def addAsteroid(self):
        #add an asteroid to the screen
        #self.asteroid
        imageNumber = randint(1, 4)
        imageStr = './sandstone_'+str(imageNumber)+'.png'
        tmpAsteroid = Asteroid(imageStr)
        tmpAsteroid.x = Window.width*0.99
 
        #randomize y position
        ypos = randint(1, 16)
        ypos = ypos*Window.height*.0625
        tmpAsteroid.y = ypos
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_y = 0
        vel = 550#randint(10,25)
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_x = -0.1*vel
        self.asteroidList.append(tmpAsteroid)
        self.add_widget(tmpAsteroid)
 
    def drawTouchResponse(self,x,y):
        #draw the arrows directly onto the canvas
        with self.canvas:
            tmpSize = Window.width*0.07, Window.width*0.07
            tmpPos = (x-self.width/4,y-self.height/4)
            self.arrowRect = Rectangle(source='./flame1.png',pos=tmpPos, size = tmpSize)
            #schedule removal
            def removeArrows(arrow, *largs):
                self.canvas.remove(arrow)
            def changeExplosion(rect, newSource, *largs):
                rect.source = newSource
            #schedule explosion two
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect, './flame2.png'), 0.15)
        #schedule explosion three
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect, './flame3.png'), 0.3)
        #schedule explosoin four
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect, './flame4.png'), 0.45)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeArrows, self.arrowRect), 0.6)
 
    #handle input events
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.ship.impulse = 3
        self.ship.grav = -0.1
        self.drawTouchResponse(touch.x, touch.y)
 
    def showScore(self):
        #this function will draw the score keeping widget, tabulate the score
        #and rank with stars
        self.scoreWidget = ScoreWidget()
        self.scoreWidget.asteroidScore = self.asteroidScore #pass on score
        self.scoreWidget.prepare()
        self.add_widget(self.scoreWidget)
 
    def removeScore(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.scoreWidget)
 
    def gameOver(self):
        #add a restart button
        restartButton = MyButton(text='Try Again')
        #restartButton.background_color = (.5,.5,1,.2)
        def restart_button(obj):
            #reset game
            self.removeScore()
 
            for k in self.asteroidList:
                self.remove_widget(k)
                self.ship.xpos = Window.width*0.25
                self.ship.ypos = Window.height*0.5
                self.minProb = 1780
                self.asteroidScore = 0
                self.asteroidList = []
 
            self.parent.remove_widget(restartButton)
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/60.0)
            restartButton.size = (Window.width*.3,Window.width*.1)
            restartButton.pos = Window.width*0.5-restartButton.width/2, Window.height*0.53
            restartButton.bind(on_release=restart_button)
            #we will want to bind the parent to listen for things from certain bubbles
 
        #*** It's important that the parent get the button so you can click on it
        #otherwise you can't click through the main game's canvas
            self.parent.add_widget(restartButton)
 
        #now draw the score widget
            self.showScore()
 
    def update(self, dt):
#This update function is the main update function for the game
#All of the game logic has its origin here
#events are setup here as well
 
        #update game objects
        #update ship
        self.ship.update()
        #update asteroids
        #randomly add an asteroid
        tmpCount = randint(1, 1800)
        if tmpCount > self.minProb:
            self.addAsteroid()
            if self.minProb < 1300:
                self.minProb = 1300
            self.minProb -= 1
 
        for k in self.asteroidList:
            #check for collision with ship
            if k.collide_widget(self.ship):
        #game over routine
                self.gameOver()
                Clock.unschedule(self.update)
                #add reset button
                self.ship.explode()
                k.update()
                #check to see if asteroid is off of screen
            if k.x < -100:
            #since it's off the screen, remove the asteroid
 
                self.remove_widget(k)
                self.asteroidScore += 1
 
                #remove asteroids off screen
                tmpAsteroidList = self.asteroidList
                tmpAsteroidList[:] = [x for x in tmpAsteroidList if (x.x > - 100)]
                self.asteroidList = tmpAsteroidList
 
 
class ClientApp(App):
    def build(self):
       #this is where the root widget goes
       #should be a canvas
       self.parent = Widget() #
 
       self.app = GUI()
       #Start the game clock (runs update function once every (1/60) seconds
       #Clock.schedule_interval(app.update, 1.0/60.0)
       #add the start menu
       self.sm = SmartStartMenu()
       self.sm.buildUp()
       def check_button(obj):
       #check to see which button was pressed
           if self.sm.buttonText == 'start':
           #remove menu
              self.parent.remove_widget(self.sm)
              #start the game
              print ' we should start the game now'
              Clock.unschedule(self.app.update)
              Clock.schedule_interval(self.app.update, 1.0/60.0)
              try:
                  self.parent.remove_widget(self.aboutText)
              except:
                  pass
           if self.sm.buttonText == 'about':
              self.aboutText = Label(text = 'Flappy Ship is made by Molecular Flow Games \n Check out: https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com')
              self.aboutText.pos = (Window.width*0.45,Window.height*0.35)
              self.parent.add_widget(self.aboutText)
       #bind a callback function that repsonds to event 'on_button_release' by calling function check_button
       self.sm.bind(on_button_release = check_button)
       #setup listeners for smartstartmenu
       self.parent.add_widget(self.sm)
       self.parent.add_widget(self.app) #use this hierarchy to make it easy to deal w/buttons
       return self.parent
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

Comment: The answer is no, because your code example doesn't seem to include and game over function, and you haven't explained what about the output doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: I've have now entered the entire code for more clarity.